# How to load custom AMD modules when using Dojo via CDN?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I am using google's CDN and also trying to load my own AMD modules using their loader. I know I'm doing something wrong but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.0/dojo/dojo.js" 
            type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="async:true,parseOnLoad:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/_base/kernel", "dojo/_base/loader", "dojo/parser"], function(dojo){
            dojo.registerModulePath("pgGallery", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/js");
        });
        require(["pgGallery/Message"], function(m){
            m.success("foo");
        });
    </script>
```

http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/Message.js is the location of the module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out how to do it here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/cross-domain.html under "Using CDN with Local modules".

The example from the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        packages: [
            {
                name: "my",
                location: "/absolute/path/to/local/modules"
            }
        ]
    };
</script>

<!-- Bootstrap Dojo From Google's CDN -->
<!-- removing the protocol from src url auto detects if current page is served via http or https and also loads the dojo resources from matching protocol -->
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["my/FooModule"], function(FooModule){
        // ...
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's why I love require.js - it has no problems with cross-domain loading of AMD modules.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that is supposed to work, which I am using is this.  Note the ".js".  Somehow the loader treats that differently.

```
require(["pgGallery/Message.js"], function(m){
        m.success("foo");
    });
```

See: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/loader/amd.html.

> If moduleId begins with a protocol (for example, “http:”) or a forward-slash, or ends with a ”.js” suffix, assume the request is for an arbitrary chunk of JavaScript, not a module.

What I do not know is if this is best practice or not.